# Resize 3D data in tensorflow like tf.image.resize_images

Tags: 3d, tensorflow, resize, gpu, scale

I need to resize some 3D data, like in the `tf.image.resize_images` method for 2d data.

I was thinking I could try and run `tf.image.resize_images` on it in a loop and swap axes, but I thought there must be an easier way. Simple nearest neighbour should be fine.

Any ideas? It's not ideal, but I could settle for the case where the data is just 0 or 1 and use something like:

```
tf.where(boolMap, tf.fill(data_im*2, 0), tf.fill(data_im*2), 1)
```

But I'm not sure how to get `boolMap`. Would use of `tf.while_loop` to go over all the values dramatically decrease performance? i feel like it would on GPU unless the have some kind of automatic loop parallelisation.

The data is a tensor of size `[batch_size, width, height, depth, 1]`

Thanks in advance.

N.B The output dimensions should be:

`[batch_size, width*scale, height*scale, depth*scale, 1]`

I have come up with this:

```
def resize3D(self, input_layer, width_factor, height_factor, depth_factor):
    shape = input_layer.shape
    print(shape)
    rsz1 = tf.image.resize_images(tf.reshape(input_layer, [shape[0], shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]*shape[4]]), [shape[1]*width_factor, shape[2]*height_factor])
    rsz2 = tf.image.resize_images(tf.reshape(tf.transpose(tf.reshape(rsz1, [shape[0], shape[1]*width_factor, shape[2]*height_factor, shape[3], shape[4]]), [0, 3, 2, 1, 4]), [shape[0], shape[3], shape[2]*height_factor, shape[1]*width_factor*shape[4]]), [shape[3]*depth_factor, shape[2]*height_factor])

    return tf.transpose(tf.reshape(rsz2, [shape[0], shape[3]*depth_factor, shape[2]*height_factor, shape[1]*width_factor, shape[4]]), [0, 3, 2, 1, 4])
```

Which turns:

[image: Original]

into:

[image: resized]

I believe nearest neighbour shouldn't have the stair-casing effect (I intentionally removed the colour).

Hars answer works correctly, however I would like to know whats wrong with mine if anyone can crack it.

Comment: what is your 3D data format?

Comment: It is a tensor of size [batch_size, width, height, depth, 1] with type float32, the 5 dimension with value 1 might change to a 3 at some point

Comment: I mean what kind of 3D data do you use? depth map, volume, point cloud, ...

Comment: Ah, sorry. A voxel format. 3D Cartesian coordinate grid with colour or on/off.

Comment: Do you want to resize the depth dimension too?

Comment: Why do you insist on doing resize with Tensorflow, why you don't do that in the normal way?

Comment: I want it to be a step in between two convolutional layers and I want it to be fast and bringing it onto the CPU (from GPU) wouldn't be fast. I admit I could use a different more customizable library like openCL and try to link it in maybe, but that seems like more work than potentially necessary.

Comment: @arkhy Yes I want all dimensions, width, length, depth to be customizable. batch_size and channel (the final dimension) should remain the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach to this would be to resize the image along two axis, in the code I paste below, I resample along depth and then width

```
def resize_by_axis(image, dim_1, dim_2, ax, is_grayscale):

    resized_list = []


    if is_grayscale:
        unstack_img_depth_list = [tf.expand_dims(x,2) for x in tf.unstack(image, axis = ax)]
        for i in unstack_img_depth_list:
            resized_list.append(tf.image.resize_images(i, [dim_1, dim_2],method=0))
        stack_img = tf.squeeze(tf.stack(resized_list, axis=ax))
        print(stack_img.get_shape())

    else:
        unstack_img_depth_list = tf.unstack(image, axis = ax)
        for i in unstack_img_depth_list:
            resized_list.append(tf.image.resize_images(i, [dim_1, dim_2],method=0))
        stack_img = tf.stack(resized_list, axis=ax)

    return stack_img

resized_along_depth = resize_by_axis(x,50,60,2, True)
resized_along_width = resize_by_axis(resized_along_depth,50,70,1,True)
```

Where x will be the 3-d tensor either grayscale or RGB; resized_along_width is the final resized tensor. Here we want to resize the 3-d image to dimensions of (50,60,70)

Comment: @GregCawthorne out of curiosity does my solution not work for you?

Comment: I haven't ran this yet, but I want to resize for all dimensions. To do the 3rd would another call to resize_by_axis suffice?

Comment: Wontonimo's answer is 100% tensorflow, so I imagine it will be faster. I will report back later.

Comment: Two calls to resize_by_axis as shown above will resize by height, width and depth and leave the channels unchanged. I did not factor the batch dimension but I think it should still work with minor tweaking. One issue could be tf.squeeze() getting rid of the batch dimension which could be solved by giving the exact axis that needs to be squeezed.

Comment: This is what I thought of using originally, and I think it is better than the other suggestions.  The resize can be by arbitrary factors (not necessarily integer) and it handles linear interpolation between nearby values correctly based on the bilinear interpolation in 2D.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I think you need to put squeeze inside stack "stack_img = tf.squeeze(tf.stack(resized_list, axis=ax))". Because adding new dimensions requires to shift ax.

Answer (score 3):

A tensor is already 4D, with 1D allocated to 'batch_size' and the other 3D allocated for width, height, depth.  If you are looking to process a 3D image and have batches of them in this configuration

`[batch_size, width, height, depth, 1]`

then use the squeeze function to remove to unnecessary final dimension like so:

`tf.squeeze(yourData, [4])`

This will output a tensor or shape

`[batch_size, width, height, depth]`

Which is what tensorflow will uses gracefully.

**addition**

If you have the dimensions handy and want to use the reshape capability of tensorflow instead you could like so :

`reshapedData = tf.reshape(yourData, [batch_size, width, height, depth])`

Personally, I'd use **squeeze** to declare to the next programmer that your code only intends to get rid of dimensions of size 1 whereas reshape could me so much more and would leave the next dev having to try to figure out why you are reshaping.

**update to include the changing 4th dimension**

You would like to sometimes use the dimension
`[batch_size, width, height, depth, 1]`
and sometimes use
`[batch_size, width, height, depth, n]`

No problem.  It is the same solution, but now you can't use **squeeze** and instead are just left with **reshape** like so:

`reshapedData = tf.reshape(yourData, [batch_size, width, height, depth*n])`

How could this work?  Let's imagine that **depth** is the number of image frames and **n** is the color depth (possibly 3 for RGB).  The reshape will stack the color frames one after the other.  Your tensorflow no doubt has a convolution layer immediately after the input.  The convolution layer will process your stack of color frames as easily as your monochrome frames (albeit with more computing power and parameters).

**and addition of scaling**

Okay, here is how to scale the image, use **tf.image.resize_images** after resizing like so:

`reshapedData = tf.image.resize_images( tf.reshape(yourData, [batch_size, width, height, depth*n]) , new_size )`

where size is a 2D tensor if [ new_height, new_width ], or in your case **[ width * scale , height * scale ]**

`new_size = tf.constant( [ width * scale , height * scale ] )`

**and then back to the original**

If after all this resizing of the image you want it to again be in the shape : `[batch_size, width, height, depth, n]` then simple use this code

`tf.reshape(yourData, [batch_size, width*scale, height*scale, depth,n])`

**last addition to add address scaling the depth also**

Here is my solution :

we'll want to reshape this matrix, and expand it similar how a 3d matrix is expanded in numpy like this

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27],[1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27]])
print a.reshape([2,3,3,3])
a.reshape([54,1]).dot(np.ones([1,8])).reshape([2,3,3,3,2,2,2]).transpose([0,1,6,2,5,3,4]).reshape([2,6,6,6])
print a
```

Here is the tensorflow code

```
isolate = tf.transpose(yourdata,[0,4,1,2,3])  # [batch_size,n,width,height,depth]
flatten_it_all = tf.reshape([batch_size * n * width * height * depth , 1])  # flatten it

expanded_it = flatten_it_all * tf.ones( [1,8] )
prepare_for_transpose = tf.reshape( expanded_it , [batch_size*n,width,height,depth,2,2,2] )

transpose_to_align_neighbors = tf.transpose( prepare_for_transpose, [0,1,6,2,5,3,4])
expand_it_all = tf.reshape( transpose_to_align_neighbors , [batch_size,n,width*2,height*2,depth*2] )

#### - removing this section because the requirements changed
# do a conv layer here to 'blend' neighbor values like:
# averager = tf.ones([2,2,2,1,1]) * 1. / 8.
# tf.nn.conf3d( expand_it_all , averager , padding="SAME")
# for n = 1.  for n = 3, I'll leave it to you.

# then finally reorder and you are done
reorder_dimensions = tf.transpose(expand_it_all,[0,2,3,4,1])  # [batch_size,width*2,height*2,depth*2,n]
```

Comment: I have updated the question to better show that I want the output dimensions to be in line with 'increasing resolution'

Comment: This solution work for 1 channel data by squeezing that one channel dimension. But might not be suitable for 3 channel data.

Comment: Added a solution for the 3 channel data.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Use reshapedData to resize it. Later, one can reshape it back to 5D Tensor.

Comment: I am confused, since I thought ` tf.image.resize_images` only worked on data with the shape `[batch_size, width, height, n] where n is channels. So this answer would take my 3D data, squish it into a 2D format and then resize it in 2D? Would this not reshuffle and corrupt the data, or am I missing something?

Comment: After looking at this, it seems it would resize the data, but only in 2 out of 3 of the dimensions. I am not sure but you would then have to reshape your output to `[batch_size, width*scale, height*scale, depth, n]`, then transposing to `x =  [batch_size, depth, width*size, height*size, n]`, then reshaping to `[batch_size, depth, width*size, height*size* n]`  and then doing `tf.image.resize_images(x, tf.constant( [ depth * scale, height * scale ] )`, then doing a reshape to `[batch_size, depth, width*size, height*size, n]`

Comment: Also not sure which would be more efficient out of the two current answers.

Comment: tf.image.resize_images does only work on data with the shape `[batch_size, width, height, depth], but no, this answer would not take your 3d data and squish it to 2d.  It would take your 4D data [width, height, frames, color] and stack frames and color together into a new dimension which has a size of frames*color (depth) with the data well in tact.  The images would be [width, height, depth] for a tensor of size [batch_size, width, height, depth].  If the last 2 dimensions were 5 frames and 3 colors, the new depth dimension would be of size 15, each being of size width x height.

Comment: The answer I am proposing is using Tensorflow in a way that it has built in functions, efficient, and supported.  It does this in 2 lines of code and does it on the GPU (if you are using a GPU) for great performance.  Reshaping like this works quite well and doesn't mess up your data.

Comment: The documentation says `tf.image.resize_images` works with the shape `[batch_size, width, height, channels]` I am not sure but I'd presume the function wouldn't resize the channels dimension?

Comment: yes, that's right.  You'll have a large number of channels.  That's totally okay.  It would not resize the channels dimension.  The reshape function does that.  **reshapedData = tf.image.resize_images( tf.reshape(yourData, [batch_size, width, height, depth*n]) , new_size )**

Comment: if you want to then change it back to the original size use
**tf.reshape(reshapedData, [batch_size, width, height, depth,n])**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143727/discussion-between-wontonimo-and-greg-cawthorne).

Comment: @GregCawthorne - it looks like you changed the question again.  Originally you asked for nearest neighbour but now you don't want a "staircase" effect.  This question certainly seems like a moving target.  I you want to remove the nearest neighbors requirement that would have been much easier to begin with.  I have updated my answer to remove that.

Comment: I don't think I have changed the question. In the chat we had yesterday we confirmed nearest neighbour would simply make each cube into 8 smaller cubes occupying the same space, given a x2 scale factor in 3D. Which wouldn't have a stair-casing effect. If nearest neighbour has that affect, I'd like to have the effect, but it is my understanding it doesn't.

Comment: Furthermore, let's say NN does produce a stair-casing affect. I dont think the staircasing would be equivalent to a convolutional layer as you have added. Itmay be similar, but not the same.

Comment: None the less I shall try your final solution soon and award the bounty if it works :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143925/discussion-between-greg-cawthorne-and-wontonimo).

Comment: this solution does not upsample the "channel dimension" so it basically only resamples two out of the three spatial dimensions